# How to read UFT8 text file and show how many time the word occur in the text

Tags: c

I'm trying to read the utf8 text file and print it out and count how many times it occurs For example The World is good ∮ E⋅da = Q,  n → ∞, ∑ f(i)  and it should show like

```
t->1
h->1
e->1
```

and so on. But it only can read the regular character and it can't read the utf8 character. Please help me

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        FILE *filePointer ;

        char data[50];
        int idx[50];
        int cnt[50];
        char unq[50];

        filePointer = fopen("test.txt", "r") ;

        if ( filePointer == NULL )
        {
                printf( "file failed to open." ) ;
        }
        else
        {
                // using fgets() method
                while( fgets ( data, 50, filePointer ) != NULL )
                {

                        // Print the dataToBeRead
                        //printf( "%s" , data ) ;
                }

                // Closing the file using fclose()
                fclose(filePointer) ;

              //  printf("\nDone.\n") ;
        }
        int id=0;
        //printf( "%d" , strlen(data) );
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++){
         bool appears = false;
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
              if (data[j] == data[i]){
                  appears = true;
                  break;
              }
         }

         if (!appears){
             unq[id]=data[i];
                         //printf( "writing %d%d",id,i );
                         id++;
         }


    }

        printf( "\nunique characters \n%s" , unq );
        printf( "\ntheir frequencies \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(unq); i++){
                 int ctr=0;
         for (int j = 0; j < strlen(data); j++){
              if (data[j] == unq[i]){
                  ctr++;
              }
         }
                cnt[i]=ctr;
                printf("%c->%d\n",unq[i],cnt[i]);
        }
        printf( "\n" ) ;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to "count how many times **it** occurs..." What is "it"? Words as you state in the title? Or characters? Code points? Bytes?

Comment: As for how to create your program, I suggest you take a couple of steps back and first of think about what problem it's supposed to solve. Then once you have a clear description of the problem (written down) you split it into smaller sub-problems, which you then split into even smaller sub-problems, and so on until no problem can be further split. Then solve and program each of the smallest sub-problems, one by one with testing in between. And use *functions*.

Comment: Yes the "it" here is character in the utf8 text file. I can count and showing how many times the character occurs in the text file, but it only showing the English character not any special character like ℕ ⊆ ℕ₀ ⊂ ℤ ⊂ ℚ . It will showing ? instead.  But I'm not really sure how to fix it. Could you help me please?

Comment: Oxymoron? `"unique characters"` and `"their frequencies"` ?? Isn't the frequency of a unique character `1` by definition?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a *multi-byte* encoding, and that on most systems `char` is a single byte (which could even by *signed*). One code-point can be between one and four bytes. You need to be able to parse the actual bytes to see what "character" it is. If you really want to be able to handle Unicode and different encodings, I suggest you find a library which will handle all the Unicode parts for you.

Comment: Any suggestions where could i find it please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.